# Template class member function specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, member, specialization

I went through tons of questions about this subject, but still failed to find an answer that I could use.

I have a template class, that is declared as follows:

```
template <typename Type, int inSize>
class sortedVector
{
    public:
         sortedVector();
         int getSize();
         int getAmountElements();
         bool add(const Type &element);

    private:
        Type *vector;
        int size;
        int amountElements;
};
```

The class is supposed to represent a sorted vector that can store any type of elements. This is a part of an assignment on a programming course. So far it seems that the main-function given in the assignment passes both integers and objects of type Polygon to the function. Polygon is a class I've done previously.

The vector is supposed to be sorted either by the area of the passed polygon-objects, or, of course, by value of the passed ints.

For this I think I'd need two different implementations of add(const Type &element). One that takes care of putting an int into its right place in to the vector and one that takes care of getting the area of the polygon and inserting it in the correct place in the vector.

We talk AFAIK about specialization of templates.

I've tried several different methods, but have so far just been met by compiler errors. What would be the best way to go about to achieve this?

Comment: Shouldn't your `sortedVector` not also store a comparison functor?

Comment: You mean a ==? Probably, I'm completely new to this, but if it's needed, I'll be adding it later. What would I be needing it for? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ a container that maintains an ordering will usually have a template argument for the comparison functor that is to be used to determine the ordering of elements. Have a look at `std::set` for example:

```
template<typename Key, typename Compare = std::less<Key>, class Allocator = allocator<Key>>
class set;
```

You can probably skip the allocator for this exercise. The default `Compare` functor will use `operator<` but if I want to use something different I can instantiate `set` like this:

```
typedef std::set<int, std::greater<int> > MySet;
```

So, there is no need for you to use specialization here. How could you
anyway? You cannot possible specialize for all classes that your
sorted vector could be used with because you will never know how many
of them are there.

So this would make out declaration for `sortedVector` look like this:

```
template<typename Elem, 
         typename Compare = std::less<Elem> >
class sortedVector {
public:
  // take the functor as a constructor argument in case it cannot be
  // default constructed
  sortedVector(Compare c = Compare()) : cmp_(c) {}

  // ...snip...
  void push_back(const Elem& x) {
    cont_.push_back(x);
    std::sort(begin(cont_), end(cont_), cmp_);
  }

private:
  // trick just use a std::vector as storage and guarantee our sorted invariant
  std::vector<Elem> cont_;

  // we need to store the comparison functor in case it has state
  Compare cmp_;
};

#include<iostream>
int main(){
   long long num;
   std::cin>>num;
   std::cout<<num;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is something I've never heard about and I think shouldn't in that case be used, given the nature and restrictions of the assignment. I might be on the wrong track thinking about specialization, to be honest.

Comment: The assignment is as follows: "In this assignment you'll create a template class SortedVector that should be able to store instances of any given class or the built-in C++ data types. Method add() should return 'false' if the vector is full. Then there's of course a list of what the class should at least have and a given 'main'.

Comment: So, this is exactly what you need. I've added a default implementation. Although I think you need to maintain storage yourself instead of relying on `std::vector`. You can also skip the default `Compare` and can implement `sort` yourself if you don't want to rely on any stdlib functionality.

Comment: You know that feeling? When suddenly you just realize how damn idiot you've been? :D OF COURSE! I have to have a comparison operator for my class. *facepalm*

Comment: @JKase Do you know that feeling when you are neither being upvoted or accepted when your answer takes effort, involves untangling someone else requirements and is 100% accurate ;)

Comment: I don't, as I've never been the one providing the answer. I hope the situation is now redeemed to your full satisfaction ;)